# Uncaught Error: There is no metadata available for this query

Tags: visual-studio-2012, breeze, single-page-application, hottowel

*I am developing a demo application using HotTowel SPA in VS2012. Using breeze I am trying to expose the model and use it for querying the database.  I used reference for this application using this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/730450/Creating-Single-Page-Application-using-Hot-Towel-T

Here is some of my code.

// My Class

```
public class JobDemoClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string JobName { get; set; }
        public string JobDescription { get; set; }      
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

    }
```

// My DbContext

```
public class JobDemoDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<JobDemoClass> JobDemo { get; set; }

        public JobDemoDbContext()
            : base("SPAConnection")
        {

            Database.SetInitializer<JobDemoDbContext>(null);
        }
    }
```

//My Controller

```
 [BreezeController]
        public class ScottController : ApiController
        {
            readonly EFContextProvider<JobDemoDbContext > _contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<JobDemoDbContext >();

            [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
            public string Metadata()
            {

                return _contextProvider.Metadata();
            }

            [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
            public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
            {
                return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
            }

            [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
            public IQueryable database()
            {
                return _contextProvider.Context.JobDemo;
            }
```

//Some Route in Shell.js

```
var routes = [

                { route: '', moduleId: 'jobs', title: 'Scheduled Jobs', nav: 1 },               
                { route: 'jobadd', moduleId: 'jobadd', title: 'Add a job', nav: 2 },
                {route:'JobEdit/:id',moduleId: 'jobedit', name : 'Edit Job',  visible: false}];
```

But here I m facing a problem , while using

manager.ExecuteQueryLocally.from("database");

// database is a method defined in the controller

//Error
Uncaught Error: There is no metadata available for this query

This error is coming when I am trying to navigate the to "jobadd" and "jobedit" view.

I tried changing some of my code but still its showing the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `ExecuteQueryLocally`, breeze needs to know what type of entities it is supposed to query.  It does this by matching the string specified in the `.from` clause against the entity metadata.  In the metadata, each entity has a `defaultResourceName` property indicating the expected name of the server resource name (method name on your Web API controller) that is used for querying those entities.

Usually the `defaultResourceName` is the plural of the entity name, so your `JobDemo` entity probably has a defaultResourceName of `JobDemos`.  Try using

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('JobDemos');
var jobDemos = manager.executeQueryLocally(query);
```

Or:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('database').toType('JobDemo');
var jobDemos = manager.executeQueryLocally(query);
```

See the [Breeze documentation on Querying Locally](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/querying-locally) for more info.

Comment: Thanks Steve , Here is piece of code for map to Entity , I got the above problem solved but still unable to solve Error which is **object is not a function** in this function 
function mapToEntity(entity, dto) {
       for (var prop in dto) {
       if (dto.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
              entity[prop](dto[prop]);
                        }
                    }
                    return entity;
                               }

where entity is an object with observables and dto is json object.

Comment: Why do you have this mapToEntity function?